# Is the initialize method a built-in method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods

Is the initialize method a built-in method in Ruby?

Why do we have to pass arguments when we create a new object, and why it goes directly to that initialize method? And, can we create a class without an initialize method?

Comment: `initialize`: What do you mean by built in? It's a [constructor[(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)): used for creating instances of a class.
It's not compulsory to pass arguments to `initialize`.
**can we create a class without an initialize method**: yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can consider the relationship between the `Class#new` method and each class's `#initialize` method to be implemented more or less like this:

```
class Class
  def new
    instance = allocate()

    instance.initialize

    return instance
  end
end

class Foo
  def initialize
    # Do nothing
  end
end
```

You can create a class without explicitly defining an `#initialize` method, because the `#initialize` method is defined by default to do nothing, and its return value is always ignored (regardless of what value you return).

The arguments you pass to `Class#new` are always passed directly to `#initialize` in the same order and format. For example:

```
class Class
  def new (arg1, arg2, &block_arg)
    instance = allocate()

    instance.initialize(arg1, arg2, &block_arg)

    return instance
  end
end

class MyClass
  def initialize (arg1, arg2, &block_arg)
    # Do something with args
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The logic behind creating new objects consists of two elements. First, you need to create a new object within the memory. This is done by calling `allocate` method on given class (it is defined on a Class class) - it takes no parameters and its only responsibility is to get a free slot from ruby memory heap slab, place a new object in that spot and return the object. The second step is to call `initialize` method on this newly created object - this is why `initialize` is an instance method rather then a class method.

The default `initialize` method is part of the language and it literally does nothing and takes no params.

`new` method is just a handy shorthand which first calls the `allocate` method, and then calls the `initialize` method (with all the passed params) on the object returned by the `allocate` method.